# RegExp DOW Optional Repeating

Tags: regex

I am trying to figure out the RegExp for an optionally repeating pattern to use for DOW entries.
An example of the patterns I am looking to support are as follows:

```
MON
MON,TUE
TUE,WED,THU
FRI,SAT,SUN,MON
```

Up to possibly include all of the Days of the Week.
Basically each DOW as 3 characters - must be 3 characters (although not limited to only **MON,TUE,WED**,etc.  **May be ANY 3 A-Z char**).
And if more than one DOW entered, separated by a comma with no trailing comma.

I have tried a variety of possible choices, but I can't seem to get it right.

Your assistance/advice would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: `^[A-Z]{3}(?:,[A-Z]{3})*$`. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a pattern that would match a comma-separated string of 3-letter (in upper case) sequences, you may use a pattern based on grouping mechanism and using limiting quantifier `{3}` to match exactly 3 letters:

```
^[A-Z]{3}(?:,[A-Z]{3})*$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/xZ6gU5/1)

- `^` - beginning o
- `[A-Z]{3}` - exactly 3 letters
- `(?:,[A-Z]{3})*` - 0 or more groups (due to `*`) of a comma followed by 3-letter sequences
- `$` - end of string

If you need to match exact letter sequences, you need to use alternation operator `|`. E.g., to only match DOW:

```
^(?:MON|TUE|WED|THU|FRI|SAT|SUN)(?:,(?:MON|TUE|WED|THU|FRI|SAT|SUN))*$
```

Comment: That is what I needed.  I was having trouble with the optional and possibly repeating subsequent 3 char entries.   What you provided is working for me. Thanks.

Comment: I still would like to ask you to add to the question what you have tried.

Comment: I tried a variety of things, and tested them all with an on-line RegExp test site.   I could get some of it, but not all that I needed.  After I got frustrated enough I abandoned them all and came here looking for a 'expert' input.  Unfortunately by that time I did not save any of the previous attempts.   Thank you again.

Comment: I ask because by showing your efforts you can increase your reputation on SO. Anyway, glad to be of help.